# Override methods from one class to another

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, overriding

In have a `scrollView` and two View Controllers attached to the scrollView
Now i want to access a method from one of the View Controllers class to the class which contains the scrollView. so i can use the method `scrollViewDidEndDeclerating`. and if i try `scrollViewDidEndDeclerating` in the same class it won't execute. But if i try to override the method. i get a fatal error.

code for the class which contains the ScrollView

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollVieww: UIScrollView!

    var mainRead : Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.scrollVieww.pagingEnabled = true
        self.scrollVieww.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let V1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeScreen") as UIViewController!
        //Add initialized view to main view and its scroll view and also set bounds
        self.addChildViewController(V1)
        self.scrollVieww.addSubview(V1.view)
        V1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        V1.view.frame = scrollVieww.bounds

        //Initialize using Unique ID for the View
        let V2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainScreen") as UIViewController!
        //Add initialized view to main view and its scroll view also set bounds
        self.addChildViewController(V2)
        self.scrollVieww.addSubview(V2.view)
        V2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        V2.view.frame = scrollVieww.bounds

        //Create frame for the view and define its urigin point with respect to View 1
        var V2Frame: CGRect = V2.view.frame
        V2Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
        V2.view.frame = V2Frame

        //The width is set here as we are dealing with Horizontal Scroll
        //The Width is x3 as there are 3 sub views in all
        self.scrollVieww.contentSize = CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.width) * 2, (self.view.frame.height))    
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if(scrollView.contentOffset.x == self.view.frame.size.width * 1 && !mainRead){
         mainRead = true
         // if i execute this i get a fatal error in the animate method in the class Main_Screen
         let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainScreen") as? Main_Screen {
                vc.animate()
      }
    }
}
```

Now the code for Home_Screen

```
import UIKit

public class Main_Screen: UIViewController  , UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var aboutMebtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var studybtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var appsbtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var skillsbtn: UIButton!

    var scrollView : UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet weak var avatarImageView: UIImageView!

    weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    var mainRead : Bool = false

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        // Making the view round
        for v : UIView in self.view.subviews {
            if v.tag != 1 {
                v.layer.cornerRadius = v.frame.size.width/2
                v.layer.masksToBounds = true
            }
        }
    }

     public func animate(){
        // I get a fatal error here
        var buttons : Array<UIButton> = [aboutMebtn , studybtn , appsbtn , skillsbtn]

        avatarImageView.alpha = 0.0
        avatarImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.25, 1.25)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 1.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.avatarImageView.alpha = 1.0
            self.avatarImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75)
            }, completion: nil)  
}
```

I cant use `viewWillAppear` of `viewDidAppear` method as this is the second `viewController` in the `storyboard`.

Comment: What specific piece of code are you trying to access, and where are you trying to access it?

Comment: The animate method in Home_Screen Look carefully in the View Controller class in scrollViewDidEndDeclerating you can see. @PEEJWEEJ

Comment: ah...I had things flipped around in your question from what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainScreen") as? Main_Screen
```

Is creating a new instance of the view controller, not finding the view controller that already exists.

If you need to communicate between sibling ViewControllers, you will need to setup a connection from their parent ViewController.

Comment: Any ideas how i can do that i am fairly new to swift

Comment: It has nothing to do with swift, it's just working with iOS. Here are some links: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Storyboard.html, https://www.raywenderlich.com/category/ios, https://www.lynda.com/iOS-training-tutorials/413-0.html

Comment: I dont get this i cant use didEndDeclerating Methid inside PrepareForSegue.

Comment: no...you need to reference between the view controllers. e.g. viewController.mainScreen = self.mainScreen

Comment: im not sure what to pass Any ideas.?  :(